# Intellij Community Edition open source project build errors - Groovyc: [Static type checking]

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy, intellij-plugin

I'm following the instroductions in link :
https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/checkout_and_build_community.html

I get these errors during first build. I'm at the master branch for all repositories.

> Error:(138, 17) Groovyc: [Static type checking] - No such property: instance for class: java.lang.Class org.jetbrains.jps.model.JpsElementFactory

The same error for 38 different code statements.

I have no experience with groovy/java project. So I'm not sure if it is a real compile error or not. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'd check with their support or file a ticket there

Comment: I've already done. But I thought -this could be a more basic problem- that could be solved with an IDE configuration etc. Someone who has groovy/java experience may help.

Comment: I've opened a ticket on: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186850

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue by commenting all of `@CompileStatic` annotations.